# How to forcefully stop long postgres query under heavy load?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, system

I am working on a Rails app with Postgres on Ubuntu. Unfortunately for me, this legacy app uses some heavyweight stored procedures in the db. What's more, the db is quite large (5GB) and my computer is not particularly fast. Every now and then, if I pass some bad parameters from my code to the db, my computer becomes super slow to the degree that I cannot get to the console and kill the postgres process. I assume, this is due to some very expensive db query. My only solution is to hard reset my laptop. So my question is - is there a way to forcefully kill a long-taking query? Or perhaps, is there a way to limit the CPU and RAM the db is allowed to use, so that I still have some resources left to go and manually restart postgres?

Comment: `pg_terminate_backend()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a maximum time for statements to take with the [`statement_timeout`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) configuration option:

> Abort any statement that takes more than the specified number of milliseconds, starting from the time the command arrives at the server from the client. If `log_min_error_statement` is set to `ERROR` or lower, the statement that timed out will also be logged. A value of zero (the default) turns this off.

You can set this option a variety of ways, such as in `postgresql.conf` for everyone, per session with the [`SET`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) command, or even per database or per role. More information on setting options is in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html).